# What is the correct abbreviation of "continued"?

Tags: abbreviations

Assume that I give my work information in my CV with the date (year) intervals. My last position started this year and is continued at the moment.

```
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 - cont.
```

How should I abbreviate *continued* here? Is *cont.* correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no right or wrong with abbreviations, but you would do well to avoid them if possible.  Here are three distinct pieces of advice:

- Just write *“(continued)”* (including parens), and you’ll be fine.
- If you have some sort of mania for them, or horizontal-space consideration, then sure, write *“(cont.)”*.
- It’s a good idea to set it in italic, no matter what you do.

In your case, though, you should probably write one of:

- 2012 – *present*
- 2012 –

As those both look better than “2012 – *(continuing)”*.

Comment: Also consider "2012 forward".  Note, I agree that "2012 – present" and "2012 –" are better than the other forms above, and agree abbreviation should be avoided for this item.

Answer (score 31):

I believe the answer to the question in the title of your original post is “cont.”, but the usual way of putting that on an application or résumé is spelled “present”, as in “2012 – present”.

Comment: Or just leave it blank: *“2012 –    ”*.

Comment: "present" is used in America, but maybe Mr Palavuzlar is living somewhere else, where "continued" is used for this.

Comment: @GEdgar, You could be correct.

Comment: I also like @tchirst's suggestion in the comment above.

Comment: I live in Turkiye. I thought about _present_ as well but I don't think it can be abbreviated properly...

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar I should think 'pres.' would do nicely

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar, For the record, Why does it need to be abbreviated?

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar It's a relatively formal thing, so you should avoid abbreviations.
Indeed, avoid abbreviations generally, and use them where there's something strong to gain (a very long word in a context of limited space) or where the abbreviations are much more common than the plain word (*Mr*, *etc.*). If you don't know the abbreviation, but do know the word, it probably isn't that case.

Comment: @user606723: Because of the constant column width.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar If your CV has a constant width requirement, I'd maybe think about changing that :s

Comment: @Svish: Yeah I know, it's an elegant format which is not much changeable :\

Comment: Doesn't sound (or look) very elegant to me :p

Answer (score 18):

The usual abbreviation for ***continued*** is ***cont.*** as indicated elsewhere. However, it isn't normal in BE to use this in the way shown in your example. The preferred option would be to use either ***2012 to date*** or ***2012 to present***.

Comment: +1 Absolutely. `cont.` or its variants are for when you are breaking the textual flow and resuming elsewhere, usually on the next page or leaf. For CVs and other documents it should be as @Tony Balmforth has suggested.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the concise *2012–now*.

Answer (score 3):

***cont’d***
is another abbreviation for *continued* that you frequently see e.g. in movie scripts when long blocks of dialog get split up, but probably not in a CV list of previous employments. I suspect it’s more of an American thing.