# How to write “till now” in a résumé?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, dates, dashes

I am writing a résumé. I want to specify that I started my education in 2009 and as of now I am at the 4<sup>th</sup> grade (in other words, still learning), so how should I specify that in résumé:

- 2009 - present
- 2009 till now

Any suggestions?

Comment: *till date* is a common form of saying it. '*- present*' is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use the [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) for ranges. That's what the [en dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) is for.

Comment: @RegDwighт Yes, I'm even aware of it. My browser isn't helpful though. Wish your comment had just that one character so I could copy-paste, maybe. :)

Comment: – or &ndash; (entities won't work in comments but can be used in questions/answers)

Comment: This is a resumé style question, not really on topic here.

Comment: @MetaEd Is there any SE site where it would be on topic? In this case I found existing question, but I planned to ask exactly this one and I thought that it would be on topic here.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny For advice on writing, writing styles, or academic standards, one of these other sites might be helpful: [academia.se], [writers.se], [literature.se], [workplace.se], [interpersonal.se]. If you are learning English, take a look at [ell.se].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On resumes, the most common way to indicate that a period is ongoing is either

> 2009 –  present
>   or
>   2009 to present

The en dash is the preferred punctuation.  Many word processors replace a double hyphen with an en dash once the next word is typed.

Answer (score 5):

In [What is the correct abbreviation of “continued”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76570), absurd forms like

```
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 - cont.  
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 - (continued)
```

with hyphens were suggested, besides better forms (with en dashes) like

```
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 forward  
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 – present  
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 –
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 to date
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012 to present
Example Co.  ABC Manager    2012–now
```